# get week number from string date with month name

Tags: java, calendar

I have a string containing a date in the form

> 04-Jan-15

and need to get the week number of the year out of it.
for the above example `week 1`(or 2 depending on locale and weekdays in December. never mind that).

I have this:

```
   String[] startDate=dates[0].split("-");    
   int month,day,year;
   year=2000+Integer.parseInt(startDate[2]);
   day=Integer.parseInt(startDate[0]);

   switch (startDate[1]){
    case "Jan": 
        {
            month=1;
            break;
        }
........
........
    case "Dec": 
        {
        month=12;
        break;
        }
    }

   Calendar temp=new GregorianCalendar();
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    try {

        Date tempDate = sdf.parse(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
        System.out.println("DATE:"+tempDate);
        temp.setTime(tempDate);
        System.out.println("Calendar Month:"+temp.MONTH);
        System.out.println("Calendar Week:"+temp.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This returns

> DATE:Sun Jan 04 00:00:00 EET 2015
>
> Calendar Month:2
>
> Calendar Week:3

I tried (earlier) this

```
temp.set(year, month, day);
```

and was still getting wrong results.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MONTH` and `WEEK_OF_YEAR` in class `Calendar` are constants, not the month and week of year of any particular `Calendar` object.

You use these constants with the `get(...)` method. The constant indicates which field you want to get. Like this:

```
System.out.println("Calendar Month:" + temp.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println("Calendar Week:" + temp.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Also, there's a much easier way to parse a string like `04-Jan-15` into a `Date` object than doing it manually:

```
String text = "04-Jan-15";

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.US);
Date date = df.parse(text);
```

(Why are you first parsing the string manually, then converting it into another format `dd/MM/yyyy` and then parsing that again? That's much more complicated than necessary).

Comment: so thats what 
>Field number for get and set indicating the week number within the current year
means on the API.
Thanks

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

For **culturally-defined** weeks…

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "04-Jan-15" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu" , Locale.US )
).get( 
    WeekFields.of( Locale.FRANCE ).weekOfWeekBasedYear( ) 
)  // Gets week number for a culturally-defined week-of-year.
```

For **standard** weeks…

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "04-Jan-15" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu" , Locale.US )
).get( 
    IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR 
)  // Gets standard ISO 8601 week number.
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the java.time classes. Much simpler now to solve your problem.

Parse your input string. Specify a `Locale` to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

```
String input = "04-Jan-15";

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uu" , Locale.US );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input + " = " + ld );
```

input: 04-Jan-15 = 2015-01-04

## Week number

Week number is culturally defined. To access week-of-year, you must specify a `Locale` whose culture you want to use in defining a week.

```
Locale locale = Locale.FRANCE;
WeekFields fields = WeekFields.of( locale );
TemporalField field = fields.weekOfWeekBasedYear( );
int weekNumber = ld.get( WeekFields.of( Locale.FRANCE ).weekOfWeekBasedYear( ) ); // Gets week number for a culturally-defined week-of-year.
```

[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) defines [standard week numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) where week # 1 contains the first Thursday of the year, and begins on a Monday. The java.time class offer this approach built-in in the [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) class.

```
int weekNumber = ld.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR )  // Gets standard ISO 8601 week number.
```

## ISO 8601

By the way, that input string format is not good. When exchanging date-time values as text, always use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats. These are used by default in java.time when parsing/generating strings.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).